# Evaluating strlen at compilation time?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

If my code has this `constexpr` string

```
constexpr char my_str[] = "hello";
```

the type of `my_str` contains information about its size, i.e. `sizeof(my_str)` is a constant 6, and can be used anywhere a constant is required.

What about `strlen(my_str)`? Can/should it also be evaluated to a compile-time constant?

Here is an example for yes: https://ideone.com/2U65bN

Here is an example for no: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cb094776dfc5969

What does the Standard say about this? Surely not "maybe"?

Comment: `strlen(my_str)` is not a constant expression. I'm not sure why you believe your first example proves otherwise - `switch` statement doesn't require a constant. Of course, the optimizer is free to optimize away the actual call under As-If rule, and if I recall correctly, some do.

Comment: That was an incorrect example. Now fixed.

Comment: "GCC (and other compilers) treat strlen as a 'constexpr' function as an extension to the language." (https://reviews.llvm.org/D23692)

Comment: In the ideone example, you could declare `my_str` as `const` only, that's the requirement for `case`, so that isn't really "an example for yes".

Comment: The example for no [can be "fixed"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be180f6be5ab9581) by including <cstring> instead of <string.h>

Comment: Under the "as if" rule, a compiler is free to evaluate the result at compile time, if that doesn't change the observable behaviour (e.g. it must still diagnose use of such an expression in a `constexpr` context).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

21.8, 1 and 2, in the standard says:

> 1. Tables 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, and 79 describe headers `<cctype>`, `<cwctype>`, `<cstring>`, `<cwchar>`, `<cstdlib>`
>      (character conversions), and `<cuchar>`, respectively.
> 2. The contents of these headers shall be the same as the Standard C Library headers `<ctype.h>`, `<wctype.h>`,
>      `<string.h>`, `<wchar.h>`, and `<stdlib.h>` and the C Unicode TR header `<uchar.h>`, respectively, with the
>      following modifications:

`strlen` is defined in in `<cstring>` in c++. The modifications that follow do not mention `strlen`. From that, I would conclude that the signature in C++ must be exactly the same as it is in C, and since C does not have `constexpr`, it is technically non-compliant. That said, this is one of those non-compliant things that's unlikely to do any harm, beyond relying on it on one platform and then not finding it on another.

Answer (score 17):

In C++17 you can use [`std::char_traits::length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/length), which is `constexpr`, instead of `strlen`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you might be confusing the functionality of the two:
strlen() gives the length of the whole string and sizeof() gives the size of memory space occupied by the data type in memory.

The function `sizeof()` is a compile-time expression because the memory to your variable is allocated during compile-time(given its not dynamically written). Thus, giving you the size of memory occupied by the data type. It doesn't care about the value of the variable, just cares about memory space.

Whereas, `strlen()` is a function that takes a pointer to a character, and keeps incrementing the memory from this character o, looking for a NULL character, which is at the end of the string. It counts the number of characters before it finds the NULL character.Basically, giving you the length.

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function (and it doesn't have parentheses).

Comment: Depends on which version you're using. I still use it like that with parenthesis. `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` gives me the length of the array.