# Constructors for literal strings and common strings

Tags: c++, string, templates, c++20, compile-time

I'm making an Identifier class which is basically an immutable string. It maintains a single constant char array in memory, making it suitable for identifiers which require frequent comparisons.

Here are my constructors.

```
// Default constructor for Identifier.
Identifier();

// Constructor for Identifier that takes a const char* and its size.
// This constructor is used to create an Identifier from a given string and size.
Identifier(const char* str, uint16_t size);

// Constructor for Identifier that takes a string literals.
// This constructor is used to create an Identifier from a string literals.
template <size_t Len>
Identifier(const char(&str)[Len])
    : Identifier(str, Len - 1)
{
    std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
}

// Constructor for Identifier that takes a const char*.
Identifier(const char* str);
```

The method I want to use is like:

```
// using the template constructor
Identifier id = "identifier";
// using the const char* constructor
const char* str = "Identifier";
Identifier id = str;
```

However, when I run my test program, it seems that the compiler trend to select the non-template constructor, making the template constructor is never used.

I expect a solution to make the compiler select template constructor first.

---

The problem is solved. I re-thought my design and found that the best way to create an Identifier is to submit data and size in the same time.

Comment: *"compiler treats a literal string as a const char* first,..."* No a string literal is `const char[N]` which **decays** to a `const char*` in some contexts.

Comment: Do you know about std::string_view and how to use it as a constexpr constant? In a header file use `inline constexpr std::string_view Identifier{"Identifier"};` and you will have your immutable string constant. You can also make your identifier constexpr friendly if you need it as a strong unique type.

Comment: Why do you even need the array constructor?

Comment: Actually, Identifier provides fast comparison and lookup for short immutable 
strings  which only maintains a single constant char array in memory. It cannot be replaced by string_view.

Comment: @X1ngChui The problem is that when the template and non-template ctors are equally good(as in your case), the non-template version is preferred over the templated version as explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77659834/12002570) below.

Comment: I re-thought my design and found that the best way to create an Identifier is to submit data and size in the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the template constructor completely, pass by `std::string_view` (a universal string wrapper) and rely on [strlen elision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49714284/261217) instead. If the compiler sees a string literal, be sure it will be able to determine its length for you (unless this is `-O0`).

https://godbolt.org/z/qsc3MKTqW

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that when a non-template and a template constructor are equally good(as in your case) then the non-template version is preferred over the templated version.

---

For `Identifier id = "identifier";` the templated constructor is an **exact match**(since `"identifier"` is an lvalue of type `const char[11]`) while the non-templated constructor is also any **exact match**(as only array to pointer **decay** is required). They both are **equally good(ranked)**. And when this is the case, the non-templated version is preferred version is selected/preferred over the templated version.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering is due to the fact that the non-template constructor, which takes a `const char*`, is considered a better match for string literals than the template constructor.

To ensure that the template constructor is preferred for string literals, you can add a constraint using `std::enable_if` or `std::is_same`.

Example of using the `std::is_name` in the `Identifier` constructor that takes a string literal:

```
template <size_t Len>
Identifier(const char(&str)[Len],typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<decltype(str), const char*>::value>::type* = nullptr): Identifier(str, Len - 1);
```