# How does gcc allow constexpr strlen() but clang does not?

Tags: c++, g++, constexpr, clang++

I think this code should not compile, but gcc (6.1 and higher) take it (and compute the string length at compile time when optimization is enabled). clang++ (any version) gives an error as I would expect.

Is this legal? Is it a gcc specific extension or implementation quirk? What's going on here?

```
#include <cstring>

#define STR "ab,c"

bool parse(const char *msg)
{
    constexpr int len = strlen(STR);
    return strlen(msg) > len;
}
```

g++ assembly (with -Og)

```
parse(char const*):
        mov     eax, 0
        mov     rcx, -1
        repnz scasb
        mov     rax, rcx
        not     rax
        sub     rax, 1
        cmp     rax, 4
        seta    al
        ret
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YTpkQT

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: constexpr strlen is not a standard extension

Comment: Per NathanOliver, possible duplicate of [Evaluating strlen at compilation time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101386/evaluating-strlen-at-compilation-time)