# const char* cannot be used as a constant value for std::char_traits<char>::length

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, string-literals, compile-time

I have the following code:

```
constexpr uint32_t countWords(const char* str) {
    constexpr std::size_t length = std::char_traits<char>::length(str);
    std::uint32_t count = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

My problem arises on the first line of the function where I get a syntax error stating that:

> str cannot be used as a constant

when I try to pass it to `std::char_traits<char>::length`. If I remove the constexpr from the `length` variable the error goes away, but to me that implies that the variable is not obtainable at compile time which defeats the purpose of the constexpr function. I plant call this functions using string literals as the parameter.

[std::char_traits::length](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/length)

Comment: All the program have is the pointer `str`. There's no way to know what that pointer is really pointing to. Especially, it can't be known at compile.time. *However* if the string passed to `length` *is* known at compile-time (and the compiler really can deduce it, which is not possible in this case) then the length could be calculated at compile-time. Remember that `constexpr` functions also have to work with run-time data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there was an answer provided for a question of ["how to evaluate string length at compile time"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51187953/9211144) that suggested to use `std::char_traits::length` and as of C++17 the `std::char_traits::length` function is `constexpr`. I am trying to pass a string literal into the `countWords` function, is there a way to make that evident to the compiler?

Comment: @Ryoku `const char* str` is `const` but not `constexpr`.

Comment: @Ryoku If you pass in a string literal, the compiler can run the function at compile-time. You don't need `length` to be `constexpr`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ constexpr is an invalid specifier when used as a parameter

Comment: @super but as far as I am aware by enforcing `length` to be `constexpr` it all but guarantees that the compiler will evaluate it at compile time. More to the point, why is it not valid to make `length` `constexpr`

Comment: @Ryoku Yes exactly, that's why that cant ever work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why a std::array is not constant expression when it is the input of a templated function/generic lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236583/why-a-stdarray-is-not-constant-expression-when-it-is-the-input-of-a-templated)

Comment: @Ryoku It's not valid to make it `constexpr` because the calculated value depends on `str` which is not a compile time constant.

Comment: @Ryoku _"why is it not valid to make length constexpr"_ because your whole function isn't `constexpr`. How can the compiler know at compie time, what will be passed as a parameter at runtime?l

Comment: I assumed that as long as I was using literals it would have everything that it required at compile time. I can see now that `str` is not a compile time constant, but I see many solutions on stack overflow to calculate the length of a string at compile time ([such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15863804/9211144), since most of these solutions rely on a const char* parameter is it safe to assume that they simply evaluate at run time

Comment: If you want to guarantee that the function is evaluated at compile time, you can use `constexpr` at the calling site. `constexpr auto wordcount = countWords("This is words");`. Possible after removing `constexpr` from length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments it seems you are interested in using this on string literals.
All you need to do to make that work is to remove `constexpr` from `length`.

The function has to be callable at run-time as well as compile-time.

But when you call it with a string literal it can be calculated at compile time. You can verify this by assigning the return value of the function to a `constexpr` variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

constexpr uint32_t countWords(const char* str) {
    std::size_t length = std::char_traits<char>::length(str);
    std::uint32_t count = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto wordcount = countWords("This is a sentence");
    std::cout << wordcount;
}
```

Comment: I didn't think there was such as simple way to check if a function is guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time. I saw some solutions on stackoverflow before but they often involved strange macros [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46920091/9211144). Your solution seems to rely on the satisfaction of the 3rd requirement of constexpr variables: _the full-expression of its initialization, including all implicit conversions, constructors calls, etc, must be a constant expression_, which makes sense to me

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make your compiler know that the length will be calculated at compile-time. With your current implementation, `str` parameter could be passed to the function call at both compile time and runtime (if you didn't know, `constexpr` is not forced to be compile time, it can be executed at runtime too; check for `consteval` from C++20 which forces compile time calculation).

So, in order to make sure your `str` variable is passed at compile time, you may want to pass it as non-type template parameter like:

```cpp
template <char const * S>
constexpr uint32_t countWords() {
    constexpr std::size_t length = std::char_traits<char>::length(S);
    std::uint32_t count = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (S[i] == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

but, please note, that this will work **only** if your `S` pointer has **static** storage, so following would work:

```cpp
static constexpr char str[]{ "a b c" };
constexpr auto cnt = countWords<str>();
```

but following would **NOT** work:

```cpp
constexpr char str[]{ "a b c" };
constexpr auto cnt = countWords<str>();  // ERROR
```

For more info, please refer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604686/template-tricks-with-const-char-as-a-non-type-parameter).

Apart of this, your `countWords` function does not do the right thing because the above example will set variable `cnt` to value 2 which is not right.

**EDIT:**

If you want to use function on string literals, then the other answer describes the fix.

Comment: Very interesting work around, unfortunately it prevents the use of string literals but at least it can be worked around using static char arrays like you showed. I'm not sure why `count` will evaluate to 2 but I should be able to figure it out

Comment: @Ryoku For fixing your counting part of your function, please refer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672234/c-function-to-count-all-the-words-in-a-string). And don't forget to upvote if you liked it:)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it in your answer for others, but yeah I knew about consteval and I would use it but I am programming using visual studio and using the newest c++ messes with the intellisense which I am not a fan of. So long as the other answer guarantees compile time evaluation by setting `constexpr` to the variable receiving the return value I think I will use that. Thank you for the reference you provided for calculating a more accurate word count

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to avoid std::char_traits::length and use old, good template that will give you array size at compile time:

```
constexpr const char words[] = "SOME WORDS AND MORE";

template <size_t length>
constexpr size_t countWords(const char (&str)[length]) {
    size_t count = 1;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto words = countWords(words);
    printf("%d: ", words); // 4
}
```

ps. Note about difference between array size and string size. Array of chars will include zero terminator.
pss. Actually it's more like countSpaces function :)